# 'Open' command not found in window ubuntu (ZSH)

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, window, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am newbie to using Ubuntu on window and I am currently trying to use the `open .` command to open a folder from the terminal.

I have download Ubuntu on Windows 10 and have downloaded oh-my-zsh. When I try the `open .` command it states that the command is not found. Am I doing this wrong or is there an another command to open a folder when using Ubuntu on Windows. Thank you~

[image: open command not found]

Comment: `cd` is the command to change directory.

Comment: @danielkang: What happens when you try the absolute path to `open`? It is certainly not a standard Linux command. Also explain what you mean by _opening_ a folder. To see the content of a folder, you can use `ls -l`. To load the names of files in a folde into an array, do something like `entries=( * )`.

Answer (score 1):

`open` is a command specific to [macos](/questions/tagged/macos). It lets you send files to macOS's [gui](/questions/tagged/gui) applications.

To open the current dir in Windows Explorer, use `explorer.exe .`

See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141917/how-do-i-open-a-directory-with-windows-file-explorer-through-the-ubuntu-linux-te

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xdg-open` command to have the same effect as open. I know it's been so long maybe it will be useful to someone else.